# Testing Library; limit the search for specific HTML elements under a DOM parent node

Tags: reactjs, testing

That's from React Testing Library docs:

```
getByText(
  // If you're using `screen`, then skip the container argument:
  container: HTMLElement,
  text: TextMatch,
  options?: {
    selector?: string = '*',
    exact?: boolean = true,
    ignore?: string|boolean = 'script, style',
    normalizer?: NormalizerFn,
  }): HTMLElement
```

The above  will search for all elements that have a text node with `textContent` matching the given `TextMatch`.

My question is how may I ***limit that search under a specific DOM node***. For example,

```
screen.getByText(/about/i)
```

will search the whole DOM. Do not want that.